# I try to take all .mp4 videos from sdcard, in list format

Tags: android, video, android-studio

I try to take all .mp4 videos from sdcard, in list format.
But something fails, it does not work me.
when you start the app, I do not get anything, all in white.
What can be? and how to solve it?
the base is from [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html)

thanks

```
public class VideoScan extends ListActivity{

File dir = new File("/sdcard/");
String[] videoFileList  = dir.list(
        new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String videoFileList)
    {
        return videoFileList.endsWith(".mp4");

    }
});


public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                             String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_video_scan, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textfilePath = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(videoFileList[position]);
        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(VideoScan.this, R.layout.activity_video_scan, videoFileList));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path  "/sdcard/" is wrong.

Because now the path of sdcard is "/emulator0/....",You can use

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to get the file.

You can try this method.

Comment: now I get this error                                                                                    at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.VideoScan$MyThumbnaildapter.<init>(VideoScan.java:0)
                                                                                 at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.VideoScan.onCreate(VideoScan.java:73)

Comment: I think this does not e created, nothing good       File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String[] videoFileList  = dir.list(
            new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String videoFileList)
        {
            return videoFileList.endsWith(".mp4");

        }
    });

Comment: Try this.I make it run successfully in my phone.And how to modify I have added in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

/* Get the absolute path */
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File dirs = new File(path);

/**
 * array videoFileList saves the mp4 file name,
 * so in the adapter ,You need to add the path Manually
 */
String[] videoFileList  = dirs.list(
        new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String videoFileList)
    {
        return videoFileList.endsWith(".mp4");

    }
});

//String[] videoFileList  = dirs.list();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("ssssss",videoFileList[0]);

    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_video_scan, videoFileList));
}


public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                             String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_video_scan, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textfilePath = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(videoFileList[position]);
        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;

        // path+"/"+videoFileList[position] 
        // add the path mannually
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path+"/"+videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}
}
```